# Can I give a name to an element of a global array?

Tags: c++

I have an array `MyStruct* my[100];` I set the data in a loop like:

```
if id > X && id < Y { my[id-X] = p;
```

Now I'd like to access `my[0]` as `name0`, `my[1]` as `different1`, `my[2]` as `anotherThing`, etc.

How do I do this? I tried `union+X` macros, but that doesn't work in gcc (it worked in clang).

I think I'll have to write a script so I don't hand-write all the `#defines`, but I think `#define anotherThing my[2]` is the only way to give the array items names, is that right? I'd like to simply write `different1->myStructMember` and not write `my[123]->myStructMember` each time, which is unreadable.

Comment: What's the layout of the data file you read to populate the array of 100 `MyStruct` pointers? I have a feeling you are doing this the wrong way and that somewhere in there, there should be `std::vector<MyStruct>`s.

Comment: Only 2 out of your 27 questions have more negative votes than positive votes and you've asked a few questions with +3 or more, so I'd say it's not that bad. Your two latest questions lack a bit of detail and I guess that's why they have been downvoted. If you could describe the problem you are trying to solve with the above naming of elements in an array it would help. If you described what the file that you read from looks like, I'm sure that someone would come up with a solution that'll work great.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thats because you can't see the ones forcibly downvoted and deleted

The file format is custom from work. The easiest way to init the data is to use an array but I want to access certain data by variable name. I ended up programming a solution by generating a header with a script that #define the variables for me

Comment: _"downvoted and deleted"_ - That's true. Even if the file format is proprietary to your work, you could replace the things making it useful for any outsiders. What you've found easiest and the solution with `#define`s is likely suboptimal for a whole range of reasons. If you want an idiomatic C++ solution, you could present the problem with enough details. Now that you have a working solution you could also present it at https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com to get some input.

Answer (score 6):

All you need is references:

```
auto& NAME0 = my[0];
auto& different1 = my[1];
auto& anotherThing = my[2];
```

If you don't initialize the array immediately, then you might use pointers instead:

```
auto *NAME0 = my;
auto *different1 = my + 1;
auto *anotherThing = my + 2;
```

Comment: Correct I don't init immediately. Will this take a performance hit? Because it's now MyStruct**NAME. Maybe `MyStruct*const *` can help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `MyStruct**NAME`. I don't really expect any considerable performance difference: both `my` and the new variables are technically translated to pointers in the underlying implementation (ABI). In fact, references _might_ be a _little_ faster, but, again, that's below what we usually consider. For any performance measurements, it's best to consult your profiler.

Comment: @Stan _Why_ don't you init the named references immediately after the array of 100 `MyStruct` pointers is created? Why is it an array instead of `MyStruct* name;` and `MyStruct* different1;` in the first place?

Comment: @TedLyngmo because I read a file at run time, create many objects, and about 100 of them I interact with in the file and there's 0 way for me to know what the data is at compile time because its user data hence why I need to read it from a file. The way youre suggecting is I need a huge switch with case 1: name=p; case 2: name2=p; etc

Comment: @Stan How many `MyStruct`s is each of the 100 pointers supposed to be pointing at? _Zero to Many_ or _Zero or One_? The `switch` will not get smaller however you do if you don't know in which order the data is stored.

Comment: Creating references to array elements doesn't tend to affect performance if the array is uninitialised, and subsequently initialised.   The same caveats on *using* the array elements apply  (i.e.  accessing value of an uninitialised element gives undefined behaviour, whether directly (e.g. `my[0]`) or via a named reference (`different1` )).

Comment: I suspect what you really want is `std::map<std::string, MyStruct*>` as your collection class instead of an array.  Or at the very least, a map between string to array index:  `std::map<std::string, size_t>;`  Then you can invoke `index = myMap["anotherThing"];` and then say `MyStruct* instance = my[index];`